# Raspberry pi Wireless NAS router

Tags: raspbian, networking, storage

I know there is a way to make the pi into a wireless router with USB WiFi dongle, and I know how to make the raspberry pi into a NAS, but is there a way I could do both on the same Pi?

The idea behind this is that I would be able to connect to my rpi to access its files and the internet at the same time, and if i were on the road, i could just wirelessly connect to the pi to see my files.

Comment: I think that you would have trouble connecting to your WiFi when you are away from the RPi

Comment: pi 0w, 3, 3+ and 4 all have onboard wifi, can you explain why you mention a usb wifi dongle

Comment: should all be feasible; just don't let your ideas on performance get too grand